# SpaceInvaders Second Iteration - Fully Functional - Next Up New Presenter Class

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, game, vba, excel

Going to take a look at Rasta's comment below tonight and just realized I am using byref to pass everything again - DUHOH - Old habits die hard

---

I have revamped with some of Comintern's improvements particularly re naming, interfaces, how to reference game pieces, etc. I still need time re his presenter class.

EDIT: This is now - Fully Functional - but a bit lame. I am thinking shields, a type of missile that moves like it is "heat seeking" and a boss.

BIG O ANALYSIS incoming to re collisionchecker.

I have stripped some stuff and made much cleaner. Should be easier to evaluate. Will add everything to github:

https://github.com/Evanml2030/Excel-SpaceInvader

StopWatch was put together by the fellow who runs bytecomb, a great site for vba tips. Link: https://bytecomb.com/accurate-performance-timers-in-vba/

The userForm .frm file can be imported. the .frx file must be in the same directory as the frm for it to work.

[image]

**GAMELOGIC:**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "GameLogic"
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub RunGame()
Dim board                               As GameBoard
Dim sleepWatch                          As StopWatch
Dim generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1       As StopWatch
Dim generateIncSpaceObjectsRound2       As StopWatch
Const interval = 3

Set board = New GameBoard
board.Show vbModeless

CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, objectType.Ship

Set generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1 = New StopWatch
generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1.Start

Set generateIncSpaceObjectsRound2 = New StopWatch
generateIncSpaceObjectsRound2.Start

Set sleepWatch = New StopWatch
sleepWatch.Start

Do
    If CheckCollisions.HandleShipIncSpaceObjectCollisions Then Exit Do
    CheckCollisions.HandleMissileIncSpaceObjectCollisions board

MoveSpaceObjects.MoveIncomingSpaceObjects board
MoveSpaceObjects.MoveMissiles board

If Format(generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1.Elapsed, "0.000000") > 1.25 Then
    CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)
    CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)
    CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)
    generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1.Restart
    Score.IncrementScore
    Score.UpdateGameBoard board
End If

If Format(generateIncSpaceObjectsRound2.Elapsed, "0.000000") > 4.25 Then
    CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)
    CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)
    CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, 

Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)
        CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3)
        generateIncSpaceObjectsRound2.Restart
    End If

    If Format(sleepWatch.Elapsed, "0.000000") < interval Then
        Sleep interval - Format(sleepWatch.Elapsed, "0.000000")
        sleepWatch.Restart
    End If
DoEvents
Loop

End Sub

Public Sub HandleSendKeys(ByRef board As GameBoard, ByRef caseNum As Long)
    Select Case caseNum
        Case 37
            MoveSpaceObjects.MoveShip left, board
        Case 39
            MoveSpaceObjects.MoveShip Right, board
        Case 32
            If MissileCount.Count < 25 Then
                CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem board, objectType.missile
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

**CHECKCOLLISIONS:**

```
   Sub HandleMissileIncSpaceObjectCollisions(ByVal board As GameBoard)
    Dim MissileIterator                                 As IBoundControl
    Dim IncSpaceObjectIterator                          As IBoundControl
    Dim MissileController                               As Control
    Dim SpaceObjectController                           As Control
    Dim x                                               As Long
    Dim y                                               As Long

        For x = CollectionMissiles.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set MissileIterator = CollectionMissiles.Item(x)
            For y = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set IncSpaceObjectIterator = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(y)
                 If CheckIfCollided(MissileIterator, IncSpaceObjectIterator) Then
                    DestroyObject.DestroySpaceObject board, MissileIterator
                    CollectionMissiles.remove x
                    DestroyObject.DestroySpaceObject board, IncSpaceObjectIterator
                    CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.remove y
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next y
        Next x
    End Sub

    Function HandleShipIncSpaceObjectCollisions() As Boolean
    Dim Ship                                            As IBoundControl
    Dim IncSpaceObjectIterator                          As IBoundControl

    Set Ship = CollectionShips.Item(1)

        For Each IncSpaceObjectIterator In CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects
            If CheckIfCollided(Ship, IncSpaceObjectIterator) Then
                HandleShipIncSpaceObjectCollisions = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next IncSpaceObjectIterator
    End Function

    Private Function CheckIfCollided(ByVal first As IBoundControl, ByVal second As IBoundControl) As Boolean
    Dim hOverlap                                        As Boolean
    Dim vOverlap                                        As Boolean

        hOverlap = (first.spaceObject.left - second.spaceObject.width < second.spaceObject.left) And (second.spaceObject.left < first.spaceObject.left + first.spaceObject.width)
        vOverlap = (first.spaceObject.top - second.spaceObject.height < second.spaceObject.top) And (second.spaceObject.top < first.spaceObject.top + first.spaceObject.height)
        CheckIfCollided = hOverlap And vOverlap
    End Function
```

**CREATEGAMEITEM:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum objectType
    alien = 1
    comet = 2
    star = 3
    missile = 4
    Ship = 5
End Enum

Public Sub CreateGameItem(ByVal board As GameBoard, ByVal val As objectType)
Dim CreateGameItem                      As IBoundControl
    Select Case val
        Case objectType.alien
            Set CreateGameItem = New SpaceObjectAlien
            Set CreateGameItem.spaceObject = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObjectAlien(board)
            CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Add CreateGameItem
        Case objectType.comet
            Set CreateGameItem = New SpaceObjectComet
            Set CreateGameItem.spaceObject = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObjectComet(board)
            CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Add CreateGameItem
        Case objectType.star
            Set CreateGameItem = New SpaceObjectStar
            Set CreateGameItem.spaceObject = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObjectStar(board)
            CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Add CreateGameItem
        Case objectType.Ship
            Set CreateGameItem = New SpaceObjectShip
            Set CreateGameItem.spaceObject = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObjectShip(board)
            CollectionShips.Add CreateGameItem
        Case objectType.missile
            Set CreateGameItem = New SpaceObjectMissile
            Set CreateGameItem.spaceObject = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObjectMissile(board)
            CollectionMissiles.Add CreateGameItem
            MissileCount.UpdateGameBoard board
    End Select

    Set CreateGameItem.Control = LoadControl(board, CreateGameItem)
    InitializeControl CreateGameItem
End Sub

Private Function LoadControl(ByVal board As GameBoard, ByVal gameItem As IBoundControl) As Control
     Set LoadControl = board.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", gameItem.spaceObject.ImageName)
End Function

Private Sub InitializeControl(ByVal gameItem As IBoundControl)
   With gameItem
        .Control.left = gameItem.spaceObject.left
        .Control.top = gameItem.spaceObject.top
        .Control.height = gameItem.spaceObject.height
        .Control.width = gameItem.spaceObject.width
        .Control.Picture = LoadPicture(gameItem.spaceObject.ImagePathway)
        .Control.PictureSizeMode = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

**DESTROYOBJECT:**

```
Public Sub DestroySpaceObject(ByVal board As GameBoard, ByRef objectToDestroy As IBoundControl)
    board.Controls.remove objectToDestroy.spaceObject.ImageName
End Sub
```

**MOVESPACEOBJECTS:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum Direction
    left = 0
    Right = 1
End Enum

Sub MoveIncomingSpaceObjects(ByVal board As GameBoard)
Dim iterator                                As IBoundControl
Dim index                                   As Long

    For index = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set iterator = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(index)
        If iterator.spaceObject.top + 1 >= board.height Then
            DestroyObject.DestroySpaceObject board, iterator
            CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.remove index
        Else
            iterator.spaceObject.top = iterator.spaceObject.top + 1
            iterator.Control.top = iterator.spaceObject.top
        End If
    Next index
End Sub

Sub MoveMissiles(ByVal board As GameBoard)
Dim iterator                                As IBoundControl
Dim index                                   As Long

    For index = CollectionMissiles.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set iterator = CollectionMissiles.Item(index)
        If iterator.spaceObject.top - 1 <= 0 Then
            DestroyObject.DestroySpaceObject board, iterator
            CollectionMissiles.remove index
        Else
            iterator.spaceObject.top = iterator.spaceObject.top - 1
            iterator.Control.top = iterator.spaceObject.top
        End If
    Next index
End Sub

Sub MoveShip(ByVal val As Direction, ByVal board As GameBoard)
    Select Case val
        Case Direction.left
            If CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left - 5 >= 0 Then
                CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left = CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left - 4
                CollectionShips.Item(1).Control.left = CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left
            Else
                CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left = 0
                CollectionShips.Item(1).Control.left = CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left
            End If
        Case Direction.Right
            If (CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left + CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.width) < board.InsideWidth Then
                CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left = CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left + 4
                CollectionShips.Item(1).Control.left = CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left
            Else
                CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left = board.InsideWidth - CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.width
                CollectionShips.Item(1).Control.left = CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

**MOVESPACEOBJECTFACTORY:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NewSpaceObjectShip(ByVal board As GameBoard) As SpaceObjectShip
Dim width                           As Long
Dim height                          As Long

    width = 15
    height = 30
    With New SpaceObjectShip
        .ImgPathWay = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\SpaceShip.jpg"
        .SetInitialLeft board.width / 2
        .SetInitialTop board.height - (board.height / 8.5)
        .height = height
        .width = width
        .ImageName = "Ship"
        Set NewSpaceObjectShip = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Function NewSpaceObjectMissile(ByVal board As GameBoard) As SpaceObjectMissile
Dim width                           As Long
Dim height                          As Long

    width = 15
    height = 30
    IncrementMissileCount
    With New SpaceObjectMissile
        .ImgPathWay = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\Missile.jpg"
        .SetInitialLeft ((CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.width - width) / 2) + CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.left
        .SetInitialTop CollectionShips.Item(1).spaceObject.top - height
        .height = height
        .width = width
        .ImageName = "Missile" & CStr(MissileCount.Count)
        Set NewSpaceObjectMissile = .Self
    End With
End Function

Private Sub IncrementMissileCount()
    MissileCount.IncrementMissileCount
End Sub

Public Function NewSpaceObjectAlien(ByRef board As GameBoard) As SpaceObjectAlien
Dim width                           As Long
Dim height                          As Long

    width = 20
    height = 20
    IncrementIncSpaceObjectCount
    With New SpaceObjectAlien
        .ImgPathWay = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\AlienShip.jpg"
        .SetInitialLeft Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, board.InsideWidth - width)
        .SetInitialTop 0
        .height = height
        .width = width
        .ImageName = "SpaceObject" & CStr(SpaceObjectCount.Count)
        Set NewSpaceObjectAlien = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Function NewSpaceObjectComet(ByRef board As GameBoard) As SpaceObjectComet
Dim width                           As Long
Dim height                          As Long

    width = 20
    height = 20
    IncrementIncSpaceObjectCount
    With New SpaceObjectComet
        .ImgPathWay = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\Comet.jpg"
        .SetInitialLeft Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, board.InsideWidth - width)
        .SetInitialTop 0
        .width = width
        .height = height
        .ImageName = "SpaceObject" & CStr(SpaceObjectCount.Count)
        Set NewSpaceObjectComet = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Function NewSpaceObjectStar(ByRef board As GameBoard) As SpaceObjectStar
Dim width                           As Long
Dim height                          As Long

    width = 40
    height = 40
    IncrementIncSpaceObjectCount
    With New SpaceObjectStar
        .ImgPathWay = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\Star.jpg"
        .SetInitialLeft Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, board.InsideWidth - width)
        .SetInitialTop 0
        .width = width
        .height = height
        .ImageName = "SpaceObject" & CStr(SpaceObjectCount.Count)
        Set NewSpaceObjectStar = .Self
    End With
End Function

Private Sub IncrementIncSpaceObjectCount()
    SpaceObjectCount.IncrementCount
End Sub
```

**CLASSES|SCORE|COLLECTIONS|MISSILECOUNT HAVE Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True **

**CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects:**

```
Option Explicit
Private CollectionIncSpaceObjects As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set CollectionIncSpaceObjects = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set CollectionIncSpaceObjects = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = CollectionIncSpaceObjects.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(obj As IBoundControl)
    CollectionIncSpaceObjects.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub remove(index As Variant)
    CollectionIncSpaceObjects.remove index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(index As Variant) As IBoundControl
    Set Item = CollectionIncSpaceObjects.Item(index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = CollectionIncSpaceObjects.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set CollectionIncSpaceObjects = New Collection
End Sub
```

**COLLECTIONMISSILES:**

```
Option Explicit
Private CollectionMissles As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set CollectionMissles = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set CollectionMissles = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = CollectionMissles.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(obj As IBoundControl)
    CollectionMissles.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub remove(index As Variant)
    CollectionMissles.remove index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(index As Variant) As IBoundControl
    Set Item = CollectionMissles.Item(index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = CollectionMissles.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set CollectionMissles = New Collection
End Sub
```

**COLLECTIONSHIPS:**

```
Option Explicit
Private CollectionShips As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set CollectionShips = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set CollectionShips = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = CollectionShips.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(obj As IBoundControl)
    CollectionShips.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub remove(index As Variant)
    CollectionShips.remove index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(index As Variant) As IBoundControl
    Set Item = CollectionShips.Item(index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = CollectionShips.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set CollectionShips = New Collection
End Sub
```

**IBOUNDCONTROL:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Control() As Control
End Property

Public Property Set Control(bound As Control)
End Property

Public Property Get spaceObject() As ISpaceObject
End Property

Public Property Set spaceObject(bound As ISpaceObject)
End Property
```

**ISPACEOBJECT:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Let left(ByRef changeLeft As Long)
End Property

Public Property Get left() As Long
End Property

Public Property Let top(ByRef changeTop As Long)
End Property

Public Property Get top() As Long
End Property

Public Property Get width() As Long
End Property

Public Property Get height() As Long
End Property

Public Property Get ImageName() As String
End Property

Public Property Get ImagePathway() As String
End Property
```

**MISSILECOUNT:**

```
Option Explicit

Private pcount As Long

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = pcount
End Property

Public Property Let Count(ByRef value As Long)
    pcount = value
End Property

Public Sub IncrementMissileCount()
    pcount = pcount + 1
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateGameBoard(ByVal board As GameBoard)
    board.Controls.Item("MissileCount").Caption = 25 - pcount
End Sub
```

**SCORE:**

```
Option Explicit

Private pscore As Long

Public Property Get Score() As Long
    Score = pscore
End Property

Public Property Let Score(ByRef value As Long)
    pscore = value
End Property

Public Sub IncrementScore()
    pscore = pscore + 1
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateGameBoard(ByVal board As GameBoard)
    board.Controls.Item("Score").Caption = pscore
End Sub
```

**SPACEOBJECTALIEN:**

```
Option Explicit
Implements IBoundControl
Implements ISpaceObject

Private Type AlienData
    left As Long
    top As Long
    width As Long
    height As Long
    ImgPathWay As String
    ImageName As String
    MyControl As Control
    MySpaceObj As SpaceObjectAlien
End Type

Private this As AlienData

Public Sub SetInitialLeft(ByRef initialLeft As Long)
    this.left = initialLeft
End Sub

Public Sub SetInitialTop(ByRef initialTop As Long)
    this.top = initialTop
End Sub

Public Property Let width(ByRef width As Long)
    this.width = width
End Property

Public Property Get width() As Long
    width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Let height(ByRef height As Long)
    this.height = height
End Property

Public Property Get height() As Long
    height = this.height
End Property

Public Property Let ImgPathWay(ByRef pathWayToImg As String)
    this.ImgPathWay = pathWayToImg
End Property

Public Property Get ImgPathWay() As String
    ImgPathWay = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Public Property Let ImageName(ByRef Name As String)
    this.ImageName = Name
End Property

Public Property Get ImageName() As String
    ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As SpaceObjectAlien
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Property Get IspaceObject_ImagePathway() As String
    IspaceObject_ImagePathway = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_ImageName() As String
    ISpaceObject_ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Left(ByRef changeLeft As Long)
    this.left = changeLeft
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Left() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Left = this.left
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Top(ByRef changeTop As Long)
    this.top = changeTop
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Top() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Top = this.top
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Height() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Height = this.height
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Width() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_Control(ByRef form As Control)
    Set this.MyControl = form
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_Control() As Control
    Set IBoundControl_Control = this.MyControl
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject(ByRef spcObj As ISpaceObject)
    Set this.MySpaceObj = spcObj
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_SpaceObject() As ISpaceObject
    Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject = this.MySpaceObj
End Property
```

**SPACEOBJECTCOMET:**

```
Option Explicit
Implements IBoundControl
Implements ISpaceObject

Private Type CometData
    left As Long
    top As Long
    width As Long
    height As Long
    ImgPathWay As String
    ImageName As String
    MyControl As Control
    MySpaceObj As SpaceObjectComet
End Type

Private this As CometData

Public Sub SetInitialLeft(ByRef initialLeft As Long)
    this.left = initialLeft
End Sub

Public Sub SetInitialTop(ByRef initialTop As Long)
    this.top = initialTop
End Sub

Public Property Let width(ByRef width As Long)
    this.width = width
End Property

Public Property Get width() As Long
    width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Let height(ByRef height As Long)
    this.height = height
End Property

Public Property Get height() As Long
    height = this.height
End Property

Public Property Let ImgPathWay(ByRef pathWayToImg As String)
    this.ImgPathWay = pathWayToImg
End Property

Public Property Get ImgPathWay() As String
    ImgPathWay = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Public Property Let ImageName(ByRef Name As String)
    this.ImageName = Name
End Property

Public Property Get ImageName() As String
    ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As SpaceObjectComet
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Property Get IspaceObject_ImagePathway() As String
    IspaceObject_ImagePathway = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_ImageName() As String
    ISpaceObject_ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Left(ByRef changeLeft As Long)
    this.left = changeLeft
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Left() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Left = this.left
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Top(ByRef changeTop As Long)
    this.top = changeTop
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Top() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Top = this.top
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Height() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Height = this.height
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Width() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_Control(ByRef form As Control)
    Set this.MyControl = form
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_Control() As Control
    Set IBoundControl_Control = this.MyControl
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject(ByRef spcObj As ISpaceObject)
    Set this.MySpaceObj = spcObj
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_SpaceObject() As ISpaceObject
    Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject = this.MySpaceObj
End Property
```

**SPACEOBJECTCOUNT:**

```
Option Explicit

Private pcount As Long

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = pcount
End Property

Public Property Let Count(ByRef value As Long)
    pcount = value
End Property

Public Sub IncrementCount()
    pcount = pcount + 1
End Sub
```

**SPACEOBJECTMISSILE:**

```
Option Explicit
Implements IBoundControl
Implements ISpaceObject

Private Type MissileData
    left As Long
    top As Long
    width As Long
    height As Long
    ImgPathWay As String
    ImageName As String
    MyControl As Control
    MySpaceObj As SpaceObjectMissile
End Type

Private this As MissileData

Public Sub SetInitialLeft(ByRef initialLeft As Long)
    this.left = initialLeft
End Sub

Public Sub SetInitialTop(ByRef initialTop As Long)
    this.top = initialTop
End Sub

Public Property Let width(ByRef width As Long)
    this.width = width
End Property

Public Property Get width() As Long
    width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Let height(ByRef height As Long)
    this.height = height
End Property

Public Property Get height() As Long
    height = this.height
End Property

Public Property Let ImgPathWay(ByRef pathWayToImg As String)
    this.ImgPathWay = pathWayToImg
End Property

Public Property Get ImgPathWay() As String
    ImgPathWay = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Public Property Let ImageName(ByRef Name As String)
    this.ImageName = Name
End Property

Public Property Get ImageName() As String
    ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As SpaceObjectMissile
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Property Get IspaceObject_ImagePathway() As String
    IspaceObject_ImagePathway = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_ImageName() As String
    ISpaceObject_ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Left(ByRef changeLeft As Long)
    this.left = changeLeft
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Left() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Left = this.left
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Top(ByRef changeTop As Long)
    this.top = changeTop
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Top() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Top = this.top
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Height() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Height = this.height
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Width() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_Control(ByRef form As Control)
    Set this.MyControl = form
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_Control() As Control
    Set IBoundControl_Control = this.MyControl
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject(ByRef spcObj As ISpaceObject)
    Set this.MySpaceObj = spcObj
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_SpaceObject() As ISpaceObject
    Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject = this.MySpaceObj
End Property
```

**SPACEOBJECTSHIP:**

```
Option Explicit
Implements IBoundControl
Implements ISpaceObject

Private Type ShipData
    left As Long
    top As Long
    width As Long
    height As Long
    ImgPathWay As String
    ImageName As String
    MyControl As Control
    MySpaceObj As SpaceObjectShip
    ShieldOnOff As Boolean
End Type

Private this As ShipData

Public Sub SetInitialLeft(ByRef initialLeft As Long)
    this.left = initialLeft
End Sub

Public Sub SetInitialTop(ByRef initialTop As Long)
    this.top = initialTop
End Sub

Public Property Let width(ByRef width As Long)
    this.width = width
End Property

Public Property Get width() As Long
    width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Let height(ByRef height As Long)
    this.height = height
End Property

Public Property Get height() As Long
    height = this.height
End Property

Public Property Let ImgPathWay(ByRef pathWayToImg As String)
    this.ImgPathWay = pathWayToImg
End Property

Public Property Get ImgPathWay() As String
    ImgPathWay = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Public Property Let ImageName(ByRef Name As String)
    this.ImageName = Name
End Property

Public Property Get ImageName() As String
    ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As SpaceObjectShip
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Property Get IspaceObject_ImagePathway() As String
    IspaceObject_ImagePathway = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_ImageName() As String
    ISpaceObject_ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Left(ByRef changeLeft As Long)
    this.left = changeLeft
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Left() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Left = this.left
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Top(ByRef changeTop As Long)
    this.top = changeTop
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Top() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Top = this.top
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Height() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Height = this.height
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Width() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_Control(ByRef form As Control)
    Set this.MyControl = form
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_Control() As Control
    Set IBoundControl_Control = this.MyControl
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject(ByRef spcObj As ISpaceObject)
    Set this.MySpaceObj = spcObj
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_SpaceObject() As ISpaceObject
    Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject = this.MySpaceObj
End Property
```

**SPACEOBJECTSTAR:**

```
Option Explicit
Implements IBoundControl
Implements ISpaceObject

Private Type StarData
    left As Long
    top As Long
    width As Long
    height As Long
    ImgPathWay As String
    ImageName As String
    MyControl As Control
    MySpaceObj As SpaceObjectStar
End Type

Private this As StarData

Public Sub SetInitialLeft(ByRef initialLeft As Long)
    this.left = initialLeft
End Sub

Public Sub SetInitialTop(ByRef initialTop As Long)
    this.top = initialTop
End Sub

Public Property Let width(ByRef width As Long)
    this.width = width
End Property

Public Property Get width() As Long
    width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Let height(ByRef height As Long)
    this.height = height
End Property

Public Property Get height() As Long
    height = this.height
End Property

Public Property Let ImgPathWay(ByRef pathWayToImg As String)
    this.ImgPathWay = pathWayToImg
End Property

Public Property Get ImgPathWay() As String
    ImgPathWay = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Public Property Let ImageName(ByRef Name As String)
    this.ImageName = Name
End Property

Public Property Get ImageName() As String
    ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As SpaceObjectStar
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Property Get IspaceObject_ImagePathway() As String
    IspaceObject_ImagePathway = this.ImgPathWay
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_ImageName() As String
    ISpaceObject_ImageName = this.ImageName
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Left(ByRef changeLeft As Long)
    this.left = changeLeft
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Left() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Left = this.left
End Property

Private Property Let ISpaceObject_Top(ByRef changeTop As Long)
    this.top = changeTop
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Top() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Top = this.top
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Height() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Height = this.height
End Property

Private Property Get ISpaceObject_Width() As Long
    ISpaceObject_Width = this.width
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_Control(ByRef form As Control)
    Set this.MyControl = form
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_Control() As Control
    Set IBoundControl_Control = this.MyControl
End Property

Public Property Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject(ByRef spcObj As ISpaceObject)
    Set this.MySpaceObj = spcObj
End Property

Public Property Get IBoundControl_SpaceObject() As ISpaceObject
    Set IBoundControl_SpaceObject = this.MySpaceObj
End Property
```

**STOPWATCH:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" ( _
    lpPerformanceCount As UINT64) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" ( _
    lpFrequency As UINT64) As Long

Private pFrequency As Double
Private pStartTS As UINT64
Private pEndTS As UINT64
Private pElapsed As Double
Private pRunning As Boolean

Private Type UINT64
    LowPart As Long
    HighPart As Long
End Type

Private Const BSHIFT_32 = 4294967296# ' 2 ^ 32

Private Function U64Dbl(U64 As UINT64) As Double
    Dim lDbl As Double, hDbl As Double
    lDbl = U64.LowPart
    hDbl = U64.HighPart
    If lDbl < 0 Then lDbl = lDbl + BSHIFT_32
    If hDbl < 0 Then hDbl = hDbl + BSHIFT_32
    U64Dbl = lDbl + BSHIFT_32 * hDbl
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim PerfFrequency As UINT64
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    pFrequency = U64Dbl(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Property Get Elapsed() As Double
    If pRunning Then
        Dim pNow As UINT64
        QueryPerformanceCounter pNow
        Elapsed = pElapsed + (U64Dbl(pNow) - U64Dbl(pStartTS)) / pFrequency
    Else
        Elapsed = pElapsed
    End If
End Property

Public Sub Start()
    If Not pRunning Then
        QueryPerformanceCounter pStartTS
        pRunning = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Pause()
    If pRunning Then
        QueryPerformanceCounter pEndTS
        pRunning = False
        pElapsed = pElapsed + (U64Dbl(pEndTS) - U64Dbl(pStartTS)) / pFrequency
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Reset()
    pElapsed = 0
    pRunning = False
End Sub

Public Sub Restart()
    pElapsed = 0
    QueryPerformanceCounter pStartTS
    pRunning = True
End Sub

Public Property Get Running() As Boolean
   Running = pRunning
End Property
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be a pretty simple review, ignoring some stuff like how you're handling position and whatnot.

---

All right. I cloned the directory from github, extracted it, changed the jpeg file paths and managed to `RunGame` once. After that I always get a compile error

> Constant expression required in GameLogic.RunGame CreateGameItem on `objectType.Ship`

even though I know it is properly declared as an `enum`.

---

#### Structure

Anyhow. First, as I said, I cloned the directory. Your indentation is not right. I show `0` indentation for all first level, when those should be `+4`. Only `labels` should be at 0.

In general, your code appears to have good order, every block is a block, you have good usage of white space in the procedures.

I, personally, am not a fan of spacing out declarations so all the variable types are aligned, I don't see the use. But there's nothing *wrong* with that.

However, you declare all variables at the top of all of your procedures - try to declare variables as close to their usage as possible. e.g.

```
Dim generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1 As StopWatch
Set generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1 = New StopWatch
' etc etc
generateIncSpaceObjectsRound1.Start
```

It's just generally good practice - it makes it easier to keep track of something instead of needing to scroll up to make sure you know what you're looking at.

---

#### Variables

You missed a couple `Option Explicit`s in `CheckCollisions` and `DestroyObject` modules, not a big deal.

Your naming, in general, is pretty good. You seem to usually give good descriptive names to your variables, which is wonderful. I mean I don't know about using `x` and `y` unless they are actually x and y positions, and your `iterator as IBoundControl` should probably be renamed. A few others that could use some work -

```
CreateGameItem.CreateGameItem val as ObjectType
CheckCollisions.CheckIfCollided
 first As IBoundControl, second As IBoundControl
 hOverlap As Boolean
 vOverlap As Boolean
```

Try to name booleans as what they are, like `isHorizontalCollision`. The same can be said for something like `Function HandleShipIncSpaceObjectCollisions() As Boolean` - "Handle" doesn't return true/false. Neither does `CheckIfCollided` - maybe `CollisionDetected`.

```
GameLogic.HandleSendKeys caseNum as Long
```

This is the case number that you use to evaluate your select case for a number, yeah? You're passing a keycode, left, right or space. Assuming you don't want to use constants or an Enum, you're passing the `userKeyPressCode` right?

```
SpaceObject(ALL) ImgPathWay As String, ImageName As String
```

Pick "Img" or "Image" - not both. (pick "image")

But, your ***consistency*** on naming just isn't there. In GameLogic you seem to be using `camelCase` very well for your variables, but in most of the other modules you seem to use `PascalCase`. [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names. But, the real issue is that you aren't consistent across the project.

Constants -

> ```
> Private Const BSHIFT_32 = 4294967296# ' 2 ^ 32
> Const interval = 3
> ```

Constant naming is half right here, but you didn't *type* either constant. They do need types.

In `SpaceObjectFactory` you have a bunch of

> ```
> Dim width As Long
> Dim height As Long
> width = 15 'or 20 or 40
> height = 30 'or 20 or 40
> ```

Now there's some use for constants

```
Const SHIP_WIDTH As Long = 15
Const SHIP_HEIGHT As Long = 30
```

Or if you wanted to get all fancy you could enum (or whatever) that out and create an object for pulling it through the Interface depending on the object.

Since users need to change the path to the images, I'd do that at the top of `SpaceObjectFactory` -

```
Public Const PATH_TO_IMAGES As String = "C:\Users\Aggretsuko\"
'...
With New SpaceObjectShip
        .ImgPathWay = PATH_TO_IMAGES & "SpaceShip.jpg"
```

That way the user can just change it once. Or, you know, you could create a check that validates that the current directory of the project holds the image files and automate that whole thing, import them or throw a handled error.

There's also something fishy about using `board.height` - I don't see you set the `GameBoard.Size` anywhere. But maybe I'm missing it, in which case I apologize. Either way, there should be a constant *somewhere* that defines these parameters.

---

#### Factory and interface

You have a `SpaceObjectFactory` and then `ISpaceObject`. I'm no pro at OOP, but I'm going to take a stab at this. So you have a factory *module* that can create 5 different object *classes*. First, I think the factory should be a *class*.

Next there are the 5 objects - Alien, Comet, Missile, Ship and Star. But each one of these *Class* objects have the exact same properties and methods, except that they have different `Private Type`s -

> ```
> SetInitialLeft
> SetInitialTop
> width
> height
> ImgPathWay
> ImageName
> Self
> IspaceObject_ImagePathway
> IspaceObject_ImageName
> IspaceObject_Left
> IspaceObject_Top
> IspaceObject_Height
> IspaceObject_Width
> IBoundControl_Control
> IBoundControl_SpaceObject
> ```

Now, let's look at what your `ISpaceObject` Interface offers -

> ```
> left
> top
> width
> height
> ImageName
> ImagePathway
> ```

This seems pretty redundantly-redundant. You have the interface to define how any of the factory's objects work. *And* they all work pretty much the same, hence the factory. Maybe the properties differ, which is why you have different types of objects.

So you setup a factory to make different objects, setup an interface to determine what these factory objects do, and then proceeded to create all of these class modules for the factory's objects. I think you can be more clever than that!

<sub>Oh, and Missle.Jpeg should be renamed Missile.Jpeg.</sub>

Comment: am going to work on a way of consolidating the factories. a lot of this comes down to attention to detail and focus. thank you for taking the time to review. am going to fix up this weekend!!!

Answer (score 2):

At first I had a little trouble figuring out what VBA environment to load this in (Access, Excel, WSCRIPT, etc.).  I'm making a note here for other users that `SpaceInvadersRefactored.xlsm` is the Excel file to launch (at the time of this writing).

To start the game, run the `RunGame` sub in the `GameLogic` module. It would be helpful to have a button on Sheet1 that will call the RunGame sub.

A user needs to update the hard coded paths. They aren't found in the modules as described in the readme. I suggest doing a Find for `"C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader` and Replace with `ActiveWorkbook.Path & "` Then it will work for anyone.

A file in this release has a typo. Rename `Missle.jpg` to `Missile.jpg`

After making those changes I was able to run the game. After my second game ended, Excel crashed. Maybe a class didn't release properly. That's a tough one to find due to the number of classes you're using.

As far as code indentation, I recommend using the free VBA add-in [Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp).  I'm happy with 98% of how it indents and it's great when you inherit someone else's code.  You can right-click and run it on a procedure, module, or entire project.